# What is the solution to this system?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Capital letters indicate constants and lowercase letters indicate variables. I am interested in solving for $\{a,b,c,d,e,f\}.$ How would I go about doing this by hand / what is the solution?

$$
\begin{align*}
A &= aB^{b} \\
C &= aD^{b} \\
C &= cD^{d} \\
E &= cF^{d} \\
E &= eF^{f} \\
G &= eH^{f}
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take logarithms on both sides of all of the equations, you get equations of the form $\ln(X)=\ln(x)+y\ln(Y)$ ($X,Y$ are constant and $x,y$ are variables). Also, a variable never appears in your system as both a coefficient and an exponent. This means that you get a system of six linear equations in six unknowns to solve for $\ln(a),\ln(c),\ln(e),b,d,f$, and then you can exponentiate the former three to get $a,b,c$.

Comment: Thanks. This is very clever. I like it

Answer (score 2):

Substituting $a=A/B^b$ (from solving the first equation for $a$) into the second equation will eliminate the variable $a$. Try to continue in this manner (it will leave you with 3 equations and 3 unknowns).

Answer (score 2):

If 
$$
A=aB^b, 
$$
then 
$$
a=\frac{A}{B^b}.
$$
Substituting this into the second equation, we have 
$$
C=\frac{A}{B^b}D^b,
$$
so 
$$
\frac{C}{A}=\left(\frac{D}{B}\right)^b.
$$
Taking the logarithm of both sides and using standard log rules, we have 
$$
\ln\left(\frac{C}{A}\right)=b\ln\left(\frac{D}{B}\right),
$$
or 
$$
b=\frac{\ln\left(\frac{C}{A}\right)}{\ln\left(\frac{D}{B}\right)}.
$$
Now that you know $b$, you can solve for $a$ easily. The remaining equations are solved in the exact same way.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to express b in terms of only A,B, and C?